"Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1" when using NLTK in Hadoop Streaming
I'm trying to run a Python program on Hadoop. The program involves the NLTK library. The program run very good with
cat test.csv | ./testmaper.py | sort | ./testreducer


But when I'm run test it's mapper on Hadoop with
mapred streaming -file /home/hduser/testma.py \
                  -mapper 'python3 testma.py' \
                  -file /home/hduser/nltk.mod \
                  -input /sentiment_analysis/input/test.csv \
                  -output /sentiment_analysis/output3

it went error like the title.
Here is my Mapper:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.mod')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
nltk.data.path += ["."]
func = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
results = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    columns = line.strip().split(',')
    if len(columns) >= 8:
        movie_title = columns[0]
        content = columns[7]
                rs = func.polarity_scores(content)
        results.append(f'{movie_title},{rs["compound"]')
for result in results:
    print(result)

I tried a simple mapper that don't use function from NLTK and it work with out error. But this don't give me the result I wanted that is the score by using NLTK
My Mapper when it run without error:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.mod')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
nltk.data.path += ["."]

results = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    columns = line.strip().split(',')
    if len(columns) >= 8:
        movie_title = columns[0]
        content = columns[7]
        results.append(f'{movie_title},{content}')
for result in results:
    print(result)

